# Shrink sidebar without creating dead space in docs

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-docs, bookmarklet

I'm using a sidebar in Google Apps Script for docs to mimic `onEdit()` so text changes background color when a user highlights it. I want the sidebar itself to be as small as possible, and I am using the bookmarks bar workaround in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188812/google-spreadsheet-sidebar-setwidth-not-working) answer to shrink it via JS:

```html
javascript:void(window.top.document.getElementsByClassName("script-application-sidebar")[0].style.width='0px')
```

However, when I shrink the sidebar, the document editor frame doesn't fill the extra space. If I click inspect element in the dead space, then close the inspector window, the doc frame fills the space. I tried this bookmarklet to close the space automatically, but it doesn't work:

```html
 javascript:void(window.top.document.getElementbyId("docs-editor-container")[0].style.width='927px')
```

Is there any Javascript I can add as a bookmarklet to get the editor frame to snap to the full screen?

Comment: Can you create a snippet for your question?

Comment: Done-- I think!

Comment: I don't really understand the Run code snippet feature, sorry. But I just tried copy-pasting the two snippets into bookmarks and opening a google doc with a sidebar. The first snippet did make the sidebar close and leave dead space, and the second sidebar failed to fill that dead space. That's my problem.

Comment: Did you try copy-pasting the snippets into bookmarks?

Comment: @LajosArpad this is a js bookmarklet for a specific page (google sheet), it's environment specific, it's not supposed to be run on a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this solution is a hacky one, since you mentioned that closing the dev tools will fix the editor frame, I had a hunch that I should just programmatically trigger window resize event, but after trying it, it didn't work. But then, I found out that if you toggle hide and show the side panel, it will trigger resize event and causes the editor frame to fill remaining space, so basically, you can change your bookmarklet to this:

```
javascript: (() => {window.top.document.getElementsByClassName("script-application-sidebar")[0].style.width='0px';const resizer = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label*="side panel"]')[0];resizer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'));resizer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));resizer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'));resizer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'));resizer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));resizer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'));})();
```

What this does is basically it shrink the apps-script sidebar, then it clicks the toggle button of the side panel and clicks it again to hide it, this programmatical click will eventually cause the window resize to be triggered and cause the editor frame to fill.

Comment: Ding ding ding! Thank you for explaining your thought process as well.

Comment: Will award the bounty points to this answer as soon as SO lets me (Saturday morning)